# How can I grep 2 occurrences of string "ATAT" out of string "ATATAT". I only get one

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to write a command to grep the number of occurrences in a string, but my string is "ATATAT" and I want to grep "ATAT". I am expecting to get 2 outputs when I use command I get only 1.

```
echo "ATATAT" |grep -o "ATAT"
```

I have tried surrounding the string with ** but still it only matches one pattern.

Comment: String ATAT is only contained once in ATATAT.

Comment: You will only match 1. `"ATATAT"` only has one `"ATAT"` in it, after that match there is only `"AT"` left which doesn't match. Try `echo "ATATAT" | grep -o "AT"` for example.

Comment: You should post some real data.  This sample data as other writes, contains only one `ATAT`

Comment: You can hack the count of the number of times `ATAT` matches with something like `echo "ATATAT" | grep -o 'AT' | echo $(($(wc -l)/2 + 1))`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that'd give `2` for `echo "ATATXAT"` as input as well..

Comment: @Sundeep oh yes, that was a `ATATAT` only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the Python answer, here's a solution using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```
$ echo 'ATATAT' | rg -oP '(?=(ATAT))' -r '$1'
ATAT
ATAT
$ echo 'ATATXAT' | rg -oP '(?=(ATAT))' -r '$1'
ATAT
$ echo 'ATATATATAT' | rg -oP '(?=(ATAT))' -r '$1'
ATAT
ATAT
ATAT
ATAT
```

`(?=(ATAT))` is a positive lookahead (see also [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)), it will check a condition without consuming characters and thus possible to do overlapping matches. `-r` option allows to replace the matching portion with something else.

Or, use `perl`

```
$ # the if condition is there to prevent empty lines for non-matching input lines
$ echo 'ATATATATAT' | perl -lne 'print join "\n", //g if /(?=(ATAT))/'
ATAT
ATAT
ATAT
ATAT
```

If you just need the count:

```
$ echo 'ATATATATAT' | rg -coP '(?=(ATAT))'
4
$ # with GNU grep, if PCRE is available
$ echo 'ATATATATAT' | grep -oP 'AT(?=(AT))' | wc -l
4
```

Comment: can you tell me  what is the difference between  AT(?=(AT)) and  (?=(ATAT)). Also cant we use (?=(ATAT)) with grep  please ?

Comment: I am not able to think of any difference `AT(?=(AT))` and `(?=(ATAT))` of importance for the first case, other than changing the command to `rg -oP 'AT(?=(AT))' -r '$0$1'`... for `grep -oP`, we need `AT(?=(AT))` for counting purposes... as far as I know, you cannot achieve the first output using `grep`, you need something like `ripgrep` or Python or something else..

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way - make Python do it for you:

```
python -c "import re; print(re.findall(r'(?=(ATAT))', 'ATATAT'))"
['ATAT', 'ATAT']
```

Answer (score 4):

The long way with bash:

```
string="ATATAT"
regex="ATAT"
length="${#string}"
counter=0

for((i=0;i<$length;i++)); do
  [[ "${string:$i}" =~ ^$regex ]] && ((counter++))
done

echo "$counter"
```

Output:

```
2
```